# How to download files from hyperlinks in an Excel export using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a project where I want to iterate through an Excel Share Point export which has a hyperlink to another excel form in one of the columns. I want to use Python to iterate through that export and download the file that is the hyperlink from each row and save those files to another location. Below is what I have that kind of gets 1/4 of the way there, but I want the file that resides in the printed hyperlink to be saved in another folder, and I want Python to iterate through the whole document.

```
    import openpyxl

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'O:\Procurement Planning\QA\VSAF_test.xlsx')

    ws = wb['owssvr']

    print(ws.cell(row=2, column=4).hyperlink.target)
```

Update:

I have the following block but I get an error

```
  import requests
  import pandas as pd

def download_file(url):

    # this will grab the filename from the url
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]

print(f'Downloading {filename}')

r = requests.get(url)

with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)

print('ok')

df = pd.read_excel(r'O:\Procurement Planning\QA\VSAF_test.xlsx')
df['Name'] = 'http://' + df['Name'].astype(str)
file = df['Name']

for url in file:
    download_file(url)
```

Then I get this error:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='a2consulting_tech_5650_vsaf.xlsm', port=80): Max 
retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x0000019C39FDBFC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] 
getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Update 2:

I have gotten the links to download, however they do not appear to download anything. I completed the file path and when I print it in Jupyter Notebook and click it the link works, however the file that downloads appears to be blank and Excel says the file format or file extension is invalid. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply import requests to download the file.

For convenience I've wrapped it in a function:

```
import requests

def download_file(url):

    # this will grab the filename from the url
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]

    print(f'Downloading {filename}')

    r = requests.get(url)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(r.content)

    print('ok')
```

Now you can call the function to save the file for you. Below is a working example of a url being passed to this function:

```
download_file('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_10.xlsx')
```

Finally, use a 'for loop' to iterate over a list of urls to send each of them to this function.

```
urls = ['http://example.com/file1.xlsx', 'http://example.com/file2.xlsx']    

for url in urls:
    download_file(url)
```

Comment: @AlexDowd As far as the indentation is ok (not the case in your edit), I am suspecting about no urls being passed to the function. Please, add print(url) in order to check after the for_loop --- 
for url in urls:
    **print(url)**
    download_file(url)

Comment: @tudopropoganda it's still not working, does it matter that the files are a .xlsm type?

Comment: @AlexDowd No, it doesn't matter. I asked you to put the print statement to see which url it's being passed to the function. Can you tell me?

Comment: sure, http://A2Consulting_Tech_5650_VSAF.xlsm. I also tried calling it from a list and got the same error. If I try it without the 'http://' i get an error suggesting I add it. When I do I get that original error. Thank you!

Comment: the link is actually to an internal share point site and when I click it within Jupyter Notebooks it takes me to a blank webpage, that's why I had asked if the file-type mattered. Do you have any suggestions to work around that?

Comment: As I see you need the full url (with the domain), not only the filename. Am I correct? Maybe that's why the script isn't reaching the file location. Something like https : // missing-site-url.com/A2Consulting_Tech_5650_VSAF.xlsm  even though it's an internal file, you should point the full url/path location, not only the filename.

Comment: @tudopropoganda I did this and the code runs successfully, however when I try to open the documents I get an excel error stating "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid". The path works when I click on it in excel and when I click it in Jupyter though, it's just the export that doesn't work.

Comment: I re-asked the question in a clearer way:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162107/downloaded-share-point-excel-not-opening-with-open-python

Comment: Hey @AlexDowd wish good luck to you at the new question! If you can, please mark my answer in this thread as accepted. Best.