# Downloaded Share Point Excel Not Opening with Open

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am re-framing an existing question for simplicity. I have the following code to download Excel files from a company Share Point site.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def download_file(url):

    filename = url.split('/')[-1]

    r = requests.get(url)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    
    output_file.write(r.content)
```

---

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'O:\Procurement Planning\QA\VSAF_test_macro.xlsm')
df['Name'] = 'share_point_file_path_documentName' #i'm appending the sp file path to the document name
file = df['Name'] #I only need the file path column, I don't need the rest of the dataframe
```

---

```
# for loop for download
for url in file:
   download_file(url)
```

The downloads happen and I don't get any errors in Python, however when I try to open them I get an error from Excel saying Excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid. If I print the link in Jupyter Notebooks it *does* open correctly, the issue appears to be with the download.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is doing. You download an excel file from sharepoint. You convert it to a dataframe. You overwrite the Name column of the dataframe with a path. Then you loop over the column, downloading each path. But in the previous step, you set every value in that column to the same path, so why the loop?

Comment: Sorry @NickODell to be clear, I am exporting the Share Point list to Excel (which contains a hyper link to the form I want). The df[Name] column I am adding the share point file path to the front of the file name, not making it all the same, I know that is confusing I have added some clarification to my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `r.status_code`. This must be 200 or you have the wrong url or no permission.
2. Open the downloaded file in a text editor. It might be a HTML file (Office Online)
3. If the URL contains a `web=1` query parameter, remove it or replace it by `web=0`.

Comment: my r.status_code is 401 which I've researched is implies lack of authorization. The hyperlinks I'm trying to download the forms from connect to an internal Share Point site, which I'm assuming I am being forbidden from connecting to without the API via Python. I thought I would be able to workaround this by exporting the list to excel but alas.